# After re-connecting hard disk, terminal commands stop working

Tags: files, filesystems, terminal, mount, path

The current working directors is, e.g. `/media/username/ExtHDD/`.

When disconnecting and re-connecting that HDD, commands such as `ls` do not work properly anymore.

```
$ -????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? Filename.txt
```

Why do I have to use *`cd / ; cd /media/username/ExtHDD/`* before the commands work again?

Comment: check this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393612/72456  too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you eject a drive, all information about that drive and any processes attached to it, is discarded from the working memory of the operating system.