# Files downloaded from FileZilla have "-????????? ? ? ? ?" permissions and I can't chown them with root

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I download some files through FileZilla and all of the files in subdirectories have this "???" owner/group permision:

```
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file_a.txt
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file_b.txt
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file_c.txt
```

This is when viewed from "user_a" but when viewed as root then are correctly identified at "user_a:user_a". I tried to `chown -R <owner>:<group> path/` but permissions still look correct as root and still look like "???" on "user_a".

I tried copying the folder and fixing the permissions but it's still messed up. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show the permissions of the directory containing those files, but it's likely you're missing the access (`x`) bit from the directory permissions. Without it, you can't call `stat()` on files, and thus can't find out their sizes, permissions, owners, etc.

Example:

```
$ mkdir dir; touch dir/foo.txt; chmod -x dir; ls -l dir
ls: cannot access 'dir/foo.txt': Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? foo.txt
```

Make sure you have the `x` bit set on the directories. You could add it for the owner for all directories in the subtree with something like this:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod u+x {} +
```

See: [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/170373)

Comment: You're right that this ended up being as simple as a `+x` permission on directories.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393603/132913 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/675364/132913 for handling directories

Comment: @XavierStuvw, um, yes, those are the same answer. Have only read `r` permission, need access(execute) `x` too.