# Shared to two groups, but the directory should not be public

Tags: linux, permissions

I have two groups. ACT1 and ACT2.
I want a directory, which achieves the two group members.
BUT: Only those in the group.

How is it possible? With ACL only?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with ACL. See how to in [my previous post.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596939/two-groups-separate-permissions-one-directory/596952#596952)

Comment: Add ACT1 and ACT2 to the (new) ACT3  group and allow ACT3 access.

Comment: @waltinator assume you mean to add the members of ACT1 and ACT2 to the new group ACT3, since there is no concept of nested groups in Unix/Linux.